# Will it be a good idea to implement compression algorithm as per my data pattern?

Tags: algorithm, compression, lz4

I am having some data to compress now I know about the redundancy and pattern of data but the standard algorithms like lz4 doesn't know about the data pattern so can they compress my data better or I do it better due my algorithm to its specific to my data.
I have very little knowledge of compression so please guys please provide me some useful resources also.

Comment: Please explain more about your data. What sort of patterns are there? Is it limited to certain characters? That might give some ideas on how to approach the problem.

Comment: Also, implementing your own compression algorithm is very difficult, and often doesn't give very good results and generally isn't worth the hassle. I would really try to find an existing algorithm that is optimized for your use case.

Comment: Some String's are repeating alot

Comment: Lot of redundancy in bigchunks

Comment: Standard compressors will find repeating strings. That's one of the main things they do, along with taking advantage of a skewed distribution of occurring bytes. Just use lz4, deflate (zlib, gzip, zip, etc.), or LZMA (xz), depending on how much time you want to spend compressing.

Comment: (Please don't comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: [edit the post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38355983/edit), instead.) Decide and record how much time you are willing to invest. Choose a plain, but not wasteful encoding for your data, encode some samples and give some readily available compressors a go at it. Compute the information contents of the same data using your model. Use the relative sizes&times and the effort to obtain them to decide on further activities. Don't measure or improve lossless compressors that don't decompress flawlessly, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Common compression algorithms (for instance lz4) are very efficient when you have repeating data patterns and are made exactly for that use case. I would use lz4 or lz7 or something else on that line.

Comment: LZ7 is a Christian rap and dance group from Manchester. There is no lz7 compressor.

Comment: (There seems to be a file name suffix used for/by the suspect to be expected.)